# Evaluation of an interesting Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, recreational-mathematics, specific-calculation

Supposedly the answer is 1 but I have no idea how to evaluate this thing analytically.

$$f(n) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} 2\cos(x) \cdot \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \cdot \frac{\sin(x/3)}{x/3} \cdot \cdots \cdot \frac{\sin(x/(2n+1))}{x/(2n+1)} dx$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question has been asked already several times. See this question https://mathoverflow.net/a/263517/82588

Comment: also see this https://mathoverflow.net/q/259049/82588

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The conjecture $f(n)=1$ is only correct for $n\leq 55$, see H. Schmid, [Two curious integrals and a graphic proof](http://www.schmid-werren.ch/hanspeter/publications/2014elemath.pdf). For $n=56$ an analytical calculation using the Poisson summation formula gives
$$f(56)= 1 − 1.484870809 \cdot 10^{−138},$$
see [More remarkable sinc integrals and sums](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.1265).

Schmid remarks:

> When this [deviation from unity] was recently verified by a researcher using a computer
>   algebra package, he concluded that there must be a “bug” in the
>   software. It is not a bug, though; this series of integrals really
>   only results in 1 up to a certain point, and then breaks down. This
>   astonishes most mathematically educated readers...

Comment: Almost unbelievable

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral